# Flip an arrow character

Tags: html, css, ascii

Hello I found this arrow that I like ➣ `&#10147;`, I am trying to get the opposite direction for this arrow but cannot seem to find one. I noticed that when I found it on this page: http://character-code.com/arrows-html-codes.php there was an additional code listed (`&#x27a3;`), but this just makes the same right-arrow when I need a left one.

Does a left arrow for this not exist?

Comment: If none exists you could wrap it in an element and rotate it 180 degrees using css rotate.

Comment: @Mouser fantastic! How "good" is this for mobile device viewing? Will it work fine for their browsers?

Comment: Don't really know. The arrow I see on windows phone 8.1. Caniuse should provide an answer.

Comment: For iPhone, `transform` is supported only from iOS v8.1, with `-webkit` prefix: see [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
<span>&#10147;</span>

span {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

This doesn't provide an opposite unicode arrow. It rotates the original arrow 180 degrees.

Even better is to flip the arrow horizontally. This CSS should do that.

```
transform: scale(-1);
filter: flipH;
-ms-filter: flipH;
```

```css
span.rotate {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  display: inline-block;
}

div.flipped {
  display: inline-block;
  -moz-transform: scale(-1, 1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1);
  -o-transform: scale(-1, 1);
  -ms-transform: scale(-1, 1);
  transform: scale(-1, 1);
}
```

```html
<div>Rotated
  <span class="rotate">&#10147;</span>
</div>

<div>Flipped
  <div class="flipped">&#10147;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that css transforms aren't applied on inline elements like `<span>`. You will need to specify `display:block;` or `display:inline-block` for it to work on inline elements. http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/rd4v6heb/

Comment: @web-tiki IE seems to do this just fine with inline elements.

Comment: You are right, just tested on IE 11 and the transform is applied on inline elements. But according to [the specs](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-transforms-1/#transformable-element) inline elements aren't transformable elements and it therefore shouldn't work.

Comment: @web-tiki; still IE can be the only one that does this. Your comment is still helpful.

Comment: I just tested in chrome and FF, they don't transform the span without `display:inline-block;`

Answer (score 2):

There is no opposite-direction character corresponding to U+27A3 THREE-D BOTTOM-LIGHTED RIGHTWARDS ARROWHEAD. A sufficient proof is that if you search a Unicode character data base, e.g. using [BabelMap](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Software/BabelMap.html), for characters with names containing THREE-D, you find only U+27A3 and U+27A2 THREE-D TOP-LIGHTED RIGHTWARDS ARROWHEAD. If there were a corresponding leftwards character, it would be practically certain that its name is similar, just with RIGHTWARDS replaced by LEFTWARDS.

@Mouser has suggested nice workarounds, but I thought the question as asked deserves to be answered, too.

Comment: Yes the question deserved a proper answer too! Nice digging.